# In angularjs, is there a way to call a function written in one custom directive from another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've been teaching myself about creating custom directives and isolated scopes. Currently, my layout contains one directive that houses quiz questions (multiple choice or text input), and then another directive that contains all of the navigation buttons. Both directives have isolated scopes. What I want to do is create a submit button in my navigation directive that tells my quiz directive to run it's grade function. For example my quiz directive has a section:

```
controller: function($scope) {
 $scope.gradeQuiz = function(user input) {...function that grades input data and reveals feedback divs}
}
```

Then in the template of my navigation directive I have a button with ng-click="tell quiz directive to run its grade function"

I've tried to pulling my grading function out to the parent scope they both share. But to make that work with my responses I have to move several of the user input variables out to the parent scope as well, which I've gotten to work but it creates a real mess of code that's hard to read and follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you would not want your directives to be performing your heavy lifting (grading in this case). At the very least it should be done by the controller, but even better in a service.

You'd want your controller to be responsible for loading/initializing the model, and expose it to your questions directive for binding. Then, you can provide a callback to the navigation directive which would trigger the grading logic.

For example:

```
app.directive('navigation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      onSubmit: '&'
    },
    template: '<button ng-click="onSubmit()">Submit</button>'
  };
});

app.directive('questions', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      quiz: '='
    },
    template: '<div>Questions here!</div>'
  };
});

app.service('GradingService', function() {
  return {
    gradeQuiz: function(quiz) {
      //do your heavy lifting here, this is just an example
      return quiz.length;
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, GradingService) {
  $scope.gradeQuiz = function() {
    $scope.score = GradingService.gradeQuiz($scope.quizModel);
  };
  $scope.quizModel = [1, 2, 3];
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <questions quiz="quizModel"></questions>
  <navigation on-submit="gradeQuiz()"></navigation>
  <div ng-bind="score"></div>
</body>
```

Working Plunk of the above: http://plnkr.co/edit/VtZdoY?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, should have thanked you sooner. The biggest things I miss in self-study/online tutorials are the "general practices" and industry standards of whatever topic I'm on. Your post just made tons of things click in my brain with all of the angular stuff I've been researching, thank you.